# bootstrap glyphicons are not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

i downloaded bootstrap.min.css via NuGet Package manager into my project in visual studio and the glyphicons are not working(but all the other bootstrap functions work...) I referenced it in the layout page:
.

and  it does not work.
When i wrote this it worked but only when i have internet access:
 
  
   
what can be the problem that the glyphicons don't show up and all the other bootstrap functions work? I want to be able to work on my project even if i'm not connected to the internet.
I'm new to all of this and i would really appreciate some help.

Comment: are you including your css from cdn? have you included the font folders? can you check if @icon-font-path is correctly set?

Comment: can you tell me how and where to check? i'm new to all of this. where is the font folders?

Comment: check @kronos99 answer

Comment: Please share the code..

Answer (score 1):

Include all the required bootstrap files for fonts.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rfehs6bg/16/

```
<p>
    Hello, world!!! 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: how do i do that? can you explain to me in detail where to check? i'm new to this. thanks!!

Comment: include this bootstrap files 

 "<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">" 

also you can download and link with Local url. 

Go to "http://getbootstrap.com/components/"  copy and paste class name for icons you needed.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of not working "Glyphicon":

1. If you are using from free i.e from bootstrap fonts.

Then write is as `<i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>`

> Without "S".

2. If you are using paid glyphon icons then use it with "s"

   glyphicons glyphicons-book

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Keep the extracted folder of bootstrap at one place , and make sure you have 2 folders - css and fonts inside it. The glyphicons are inside the fonts folder.
Afterwards just import css.min as you are doing and it will work fine.